# Representing hierarchical types in GraphQL

Tags: graphql

This is an example of a problem I'm trying to solve. Suppose I want to create a GraphQL schema that models administrative entities (countries, states, provinces etc, represented by type `AdministrativeEntity`) of cities (type `City`) around the world. Each city belongs to a list of entities that have hierarchical relationship to each other. However, the number of "levels" of a city's administrative entities  may differ. For example, "Chicago" belongs to "United States" and "Illinois" (which has two levels) but Singapore only belongs to "Singapore" (only one level). How should I represent the type `AdministrativeEntity` in my GraphQL schema? Should it be a `scalar`, an `Object` type or something else?

```
type City {
  entity: AdministrativeEntity!
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use recurrency - `parent` property in `AdministrativeEntity` type. This is the most universal, expandable, manageable.

... but for savings (on scale) you can use simple [ordered] array of names.

Of course you can use both solutions (2 properties) in the same time (2 resolvers operating on the same data/db).